# SOQL to pull the Account ,Contact,OppLineItem details on Opp in a single Query

Tags: soql

I'm trying to frame a single SOQL on opportunity with fields from Multiple objects like Account Name, Contact Name ,Contact Ph , Contact Email and the Opplineitems. I'm not sure how to get the Account Name and Contact Details from opp which has lookup.

```
 Opportunity Op=[select id,Name,Stagename,Account__r.Name,(select Product_Name__c,Bid_Type__c from OpportunityLineItems) from opportunity where stagename='Closed-Won' and id=:opptyid];
```

Comment: helpful tip -- OOB SFDC relationships never use `__r`; OOB SFDC fields never use `__c`. Hence relationship from Opportunity to Account is simply `account.someAccountOOBfieldname` or `account.someAccountCustomfieldname__c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a contact related to the Opp via a lookup then you will have to do two queries. (or a subquery on via Contact Roles child object on Opp if that fits your need) For Account use

```
Account.name
```

From the query on Opp

Since you have a lookup to contact, use the API name replacing the `__c` with `__r` and add `.name` or whatever other field you need

Comment: We have lookup to Contact from opportunity, I need to get the details of this contact.

Comment: The use the Contact__r.Name (Or whatever the API name is of the Lookup to the contact